# Why can't I connect to my ec2 instance after apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I have put together my first terraform script for asset provisioning on AWS. However, I am not able to connect to the EC2 instance in the public subnet

I can see that all of the expected resources are created:
subnets/instances/route tables/gateway etc

I have excluded provider.tf because it contains sensitive secrets.

My region is ap-south-1.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc1" {
  cidr_block = "10.20.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    name = "tf_vpc"
  }
}

# subnets below
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public"{
  vpc_id  = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.20.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_private"{
  vpc_id  = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.20.20.0/24"
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg-web" {
  name ="allow80"
  description="allows traffic on port 80"
  vpc_id ="${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"

  ingress{
    from_port = 80
    to_port   = 80
    protocol  = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress{
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    name="allowhttp"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_route_table" "public" {
  default_route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.main_route_table_id}"

  tags = {
    name = "route-default"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "ig"{
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "route_public"{
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
}

resource "aws_route" "r1" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.route_public.id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/16"
  gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.ig.id}"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet_public.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.route_public.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ins1_web"{
  ami = "ami-0447a12f28fddb066"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet_public.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg-web.id}"]

  key_name = "myBOMkey-2"

  tags = {
    name="tf-1"
  } 
} 

resource "aws_instance" "ins1_db"{
  ami = "ami-0447a12f28fddb066"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet_private.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg-web.id}"]

  key_name = "myBOMkey-2"

  tags = {
    name="tf-1"
  } 
}
```

Why can't I connect to my ec2 instance after apply?

Comment: What error message are you receiving when trying to connect to your EC2 instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the CIDR (0.0.0.0/16), which does not seem to be correct. Might be a typo. Any-IP is represented with "0.0.0.0/0" , as any-IP destination needs to be routed to Internet gateway.

```
resource "aws_route" "r1" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.route_public.id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.ig.id}"
}
```

Also missing from your Security group configuration is egress (outbound )traffic as terraform does not keep ALL traffic allowed as default in outbound traffic. Refer to terraform security group documentation.

```
egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: 0.0.0.0/16 isn't technically wrong, it's just really unhelpful as it will only route traffic destined for 0.0.x.x to the internet gateway, which cannot be useful since those IPs are unusable. I'm surprised AWS allows this as a route table entry. This allows for some diabolical exam questions.

Comment: I have spent so much time looking for what was wrong with [my terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62480966/667301).  The info about `egress` security group rule was the last missing piece.  I wish I could +5