# Terraform EC2 networking broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform 0.12.26 and I want to build an AWS Ubuntu machine instance.

When I run `terraform apply`, everything looks right... but I can't ssh to the new EC2 machine.  My home firewall allows ssh everywhere, and I can ssh to any other internet resources.

If I manually install an EC2 instance in the same region / az, ssh works fine... this problem seems to be limited to Terraform.

```
$ terraform apply
...
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_key_pair.mykeypair: Creating...
aws_vpc.main: Creating...
aws_key_pair.mykeypair: Creation complete after 2s [id=mykeypair-pub]
aws_vpc.main: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_vpc.main: Creation complete after 14s [id=vpc-0396212cf58236e68]
aws_subnet.first_subnet: Creating...
aws_security_group.ingress-policy-example: Creating...
aws_subnet.first_subnet: Creation complete after 10s [id=subnet-0558eb0d5c2a4cb3e]
aws_security_group.ingress-policy-example: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_security_group.ingress-policy-example: Creation complete after 13s [id=sg-080e7fa96dc485107]
aws_instance.example: Creating...
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Creation complete after 25s [id=i-0aaf3c53023c1226f]

Apply complete! Resources: 5 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

ip = 34.217.88.173

$ telnet 34.217.88.173 22
Trying 34.217.88.173...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable
$
```

[image: aws_console_output]

This is my terraform code:

```
$ cat main.tf
provider "aws" {
  region     = var.region
  access_key = "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_HERE"
  secret_key = "SECRET_KEY_HERE"

  # Allow any 2.x version of the AWS provider
  version = "~> 2.0"
}

variable region {
  default = "us-west-2"
}

variable availability_zone_01 {
  default = "us-west-2a"
}

variable key_path {
    default = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}

variable site_supernet {
    default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable first_subnet {
    default = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block           = var.site_supernet
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
  instance_tenancy     = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "tag-primary-vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "first_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = var.first_subnet
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone_01
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "tag-first_subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ingress-policy-example" {
  vpc_id        = aws_vpc.main.id
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0",]
    from_port   = 22  # Port from 22 to 22...
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }

  ## This egress rule was missing from my original question...
  egress {
    # Terraform doesn't allow all egress traffic by default...
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "tag-sg-allow-ssh"
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
  key_name   = "mykeypair-pub"
  public_key = file(var.key_path)
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  #ami           = "ami-0994c095691a46fb5"
  ami           = "ami-003634241a8fcdec0"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.mykeypair.key_name

  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.first_subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [
    aws_security_group.ingress-policy-example.id,
  ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = false
  }

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              apt-get update
              apt-get install openssh-server
              EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "stackoverflow_20200619"
  }
}

output "ip" {
  value = aws_instance.example.public_ip
}
```

**QUESTION**: How can I fix this terraform deployment so I can ssh to the server above?

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**:

- Manually building an Ubuntu image using key auth; this works fine and I can ssh to it
- Removing the terraform security group; does not help
- Changed AWS terraform regions / availability zones; does not help
- Removing `user_data` package installation; does not help
- Removing the `aws_subnet`; does not help
- Removing `instance_tenancy`; does not help
- Replace ssh key with another ssh key; does not help
- Replace ssh key with static username / password; does not help
- SSH from Windows with PuTTY (instead of linux & openssh); does not help

Comment: You may want to remove the reference to telnet in there. I initially thought that that might be your issue. Also, openssh-server is pretty-well universally preconfigured on AWS EC2 AMIs for Linux distros unless you are using something particularly exotic, so you can drop the user_data too.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea, `telnet somehostname 22` is just another way to `nmap -p 22 somehostname`.

Comment: Fair. It's a sanity check that you can get a TCP connection. Valid point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your VPC has no Internet Gateway (IGW). You'll need to create that and add a route table entry for it.

Adding these resources should work (wrote this on my phone so your mileage may vary):

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "r" {
  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.rt
  destination_cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "rta" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.first_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rt.id
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but missing one critical piece:  in addition to what you have here, I needed to add an `egress` rule allowing everything from my instance out to the internet (ref: [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html): NOTE on Egress rules: By default, AWS creates an ALLOW ALL egress rule when creating a new Security Group inside of a VPC. **When creating a new Security Group inside a VPC, Terraform will remove this default rule, and require you specifically re-create it if you desire that rule.**).  I edited that piece into my question

Comment: Great. I'm glad it helped. I'm curious about the egress rule though. Security groups are stateful so they should allow reply traffic by default. Normally you'd only need to allow SSH on an ingress rule and that would be sufficient for SSH to work. It wouldn't allow the instance to run updates or initiate its own connections without that egress rule though, so it's worth starting where you have by allowing all traffic egress.

Comment: I can't find an authoritative AWS security-group reference that explains whether security-groups are stateful or not.  However, my tests make it obvious that I cannot make a tcp connection into the new EC2 machine on port 22 unless I include an allow-all egress rule.  I also checked whether EC2 is doing a DNS reverse-lookup on my source-ip when I ssh in; however, EC2 isn't doing an IP lookup (and thus doesn't suffer an initial ssh connection delay if DNS times out).

Comment: I tried to copy paste the text from AWS docs but I'm on my phone and the iOS app is not letting me paste it into a comment. AWS buries the lede a bit with this. When I looked under Security Group Basics, several items down I found "Security groups are stateful..." here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: You're right that the docs say the security-group rules are stateful by default (with some exceptions); however, their behavior is clearly not stateful in my ssh tests (if I remove my `egress` rule).  Perhaps I'm hitting a bug?

Comment: That's troubling and unexpected. I'm happy to discuss further. If you remove the egress rule manually after you terraform apply, does SSH break?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216329/discussion-between-mike-pennington-and-alain-odea).

Comment: @MikePennington sorry. My phone dropped its data connection and I struggled to join the chat. I did explain the situation somewhat in there once I joined. Sorry about that.